# How to go about messages in Dead Letter Queue

Tags: jms, weblogic, ibm-mq, dead-letter

We are using WebLogic 10.3.6.0 and IBM MQ 7.5.
Application design is to send messages to a dead letter queue (in WebLogic) on re-delivery. The re-delivery happens as the first delivery has failed due to some network issue or database data source failure.

My Client wants a way to browse the messages in the dead letter queue from the application GUI and pull them for processing when the network issue or data source issue has been resolved.

What is the best way to go about this?

I cam across QueueBrowser coupled with activemq or some other implementation. Is QueueBrowser possible with WebLogic? Please suggest on best ways to achieve this requirement.
Kindly pardon if my question is too naive. I am only a PL/SQL programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Valerie is referring to the SYSTEM DLQ and application should never ever write to it.  Application's should have there own DLQ.

i.e.  If your application queue is called 'TEST.Q1' then your application DLQ should be called 'TEST.Q1.DLQ'.

There is a whole long list of MQ tools [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html) to view messages and manage your MQ environment.

Answer (score 0):

Is the application actually designed to write to the DLQ?  If so, that is a very poor design.  The DLQ is for the queue manager and MQ software to place messages which can not be delivered.  The application should not be writing to the DLQ.

As for how to view messages on DLQ, that can be done with the MQ Explorer GUI.  Or to write a script, use the DLQ handler ([runmqdlq](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083420_.htm))  with a rules table for processing messages.